# Starting MongoDB : ./bin/mongod No such file or directory

Tags: mongodb

After installing MongoDB with ruby gems

```
 gem install mongodb
```

In my user/sites directory, I did

```
sudo mkdir -p /data/db/  
sudo chown `id -u` /data/db
```

However, this didn't create those directories in user/sites. I had to back up a few levels to access them.

the instructions I am following then told me to

```
cd to your MongoDB bin directory or type in the complete path to it. You'll need to start mongod.

$ ./bin/mongod
```

I did this command inside  user/sites and also, after backing up a few levels, inside the data directory, and inside the data/db directory. However, each time I got

```
./bin/mongod: No such file or directory
```

**1st question:** Know what's wrong?

Once and if I get that to work, I will have to do this to start the mongo shell

```
./bin/mongo
```

**2nd question:** where will i run that command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure installing mongo as a Ruby gem actually installs MongoDB? Looks to me like you're only installing the ruby driver. Here's some docs on how to [install MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. It turned out i was using the 32bit version of mongo on a 64 bit ubuntu machine.

I got this from the link below:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/b8rhUllEhlA

Answer (score 0):

**Wrong Path:**

```
$ sudo chown -R sqy1 /Users/sqy1/data/db
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows go to git bash/cmd then type "cd" , that will bring you to root directory then type "mongod" and press type, this must start you mongoDB. I did this and it worked